# Splunk email view result link doesn't work

Tags: splunk

Splunk view results page attaches 8000 port to the link when i click on the view result in the email! In the server setting page the web port is set to 8000 . How do i resolve this ?

```
 Splunk Web
 Run Splunk Web
 Web port * ---8000
```

Comment: Can you give us more about the context, didn't understood ...

Comment: @CyrilleGuimezanes When I am trying to open the view results from the spunk alerts, it gets redirect to splunk.xxx.com:80 where the link breaks. When I remove 80 , from the link it works normally. I am not sure where I make this change in the setting to open with out 80?

Answer (score 0):

Port 8000 is the default webserver port that the main web url for splunk opens with.  As long as I have used splunk I have had no need to change this port.  The URL is getting "cut off".  What exactly do you mean by this?  Can you right click the link and perhaps choose "open in new tab" and see if the URL is any different?  Is the entire URL highlighted as a link in the email or are the words "View Results" the link and it is embedded?

I would also double check the alert and verify that you have checked the box for the "Link to the Alert" and the "Link to the Results" in the alert setup page.

If all of this looks ok, check the alert_actions.conf file.  In this file you can set the hostname and port you use for web links.  It perhaps is configured differently in this file then you would like.  You may want make sure the port here is set to 8000 and not 80.  Look under "Hostname" for what value is set.

http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Alertactionsconf

Answer (score 0):

This is probably you have not link your result to proper host name.

You can link host name in the email settings.

Goto  splunk --> setting --> server settings --> Email settings --> update the Link host name parameter with your LB / Splunk server with out port 80

Answer (score 0):

The email link will leverage the settings in 'Settings > Server Settings > General Settings'

Splunk uses the `Default host name:Web Port` fields to create the URL.

[image]

This gets more complicated if you're using a load balancer in front of your search heads.